# npm install -> tunneling socket could not be established

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm, tunneling

This error message has been answered quite a few times on Stack Overflow, but all the solutions didn't work for me.

Whenever I do `npm install` I get the following message:

```
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Repos\[repo-name]
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
```

It has worked a lot of times before, but it suddenly stopped working. The only thing that has changed, that I can remember, is that I've installed VMWare Player. But I don't see why that is related.

Sometimes, instead of `statusCode=407` the message say `cause=Parse Error`.

I've tried the following:

- Setting the proxy with `npm config set proxy` and `npm config set https-proxy`
- Changing the registry to http://registry.npmjs.org
- Setting `strict-ssl` to false
- Clearing npm's cache with `npm cache clean`

I'm out of options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution.

I changed my domain password a few days ago, I needed to update the cntlm ini file

Answer (score 4):

If you are behind a proxy you must:

```
npm config set proxy https://username:password@proxy:port

npm config set https-proxy https://username:password@proxy:port
```

If you don't use user and password, just avoid "**username:password@**" in line command.